# If $T$ is a contraction on a Banach space, then $I-T$ is an automorphism - why does the space need to be Banach?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}$I am given the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a nonempty Banach space and $T\in\L(X,X)$ such that $\|T\|\lt1$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the standard operator norm. Show that $I-T$ is an automorphism (hint: use the contraction mapping principle)

Royden defines an isomorphism of a linear space to be a continuous linear bijection with continuous inverse, i.e. a bijective linear map which is bounded in both directions.

First I show bijectivity:

> If $(I-T)x=0$ for any $x\in X$, then $x=Tx$. However, $T$ has only one fixed point, namely the $0$ element, since if $x,y$ are two distinct fixed points of $T$ then $\|x-y\|=\|T(x)-T(y)\|\lt\|x-y\|$ which cannot be. Therefore $\ker(I-T)=\{0\}$ and so it is injective. As it is a self-map on $X$, and linear, the theory of basis vectors quickly shows that injectivity implies surjectivity (alternatively consider the rank-nullity theorem). $I-T$ is then bijective.

Then $\|I-T\|\le1+\|T\|\lt2$ so it is continuous in the forward direction. I just need to show that its inverse is continuous/bounded; call the inverse $J$. Since $\|\cdot\|$ enforces a norm with the triangle inequality, the reverse triangle inequality holds:

$$0\lt c=|\|I\|-\|T\||\le\|I-T\|\le2$$

Then $c\|x\|\le\|(I-T)x\|\le2\|x\|$, and I can put $x=Jy$ and find:

$$0\lt c\|Jy\|\le\|y\|\le2\|Jy\|$$

In particular, $\|Jy\|\le\frac{1}{c}\|y\|$ for all $y$ and so $J$ is continuous.

So we are done - why was the space required to be Banach? Further, why was the contraction mapping principle required? I expect these have the same answer.

Edit: I've realised, with the help of Jose and SilverDoe, that my bijectivity proof is flawed. Instead, using the hint and the Banach property, note that $\exists y\in X:\not\exists x\in X:(I-T)x=y$ is equivalent to the statement: there is no fixed point of the map $x\mapsto T(x)+y$, but the contraction mapping principle shows that this is false since $T_y:x\mapsto T(x)+y$ satisfies $\|T_y(u-v)\|=\|T(u-v)\|\le \|T\|\cdot\|u-v\|$ where $\|T\|\lt1$.

Comment: "injectivity implies surjectivity", "rank-nullity theorem", "theory of basis vectors" etc. : what if $X$ has infinite dimension ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe point taken - I studied a lot of linear algebra in the past, but *all* of it concerned itself with finite dimensions! It is a shame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is wrong, because it is *not* true that every injective linear map from a vector space $X$ into itself is surjective. Take, for instance, $X=\{\text{sequences of real numbers}\}$ and$$f(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)=(0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots).$$The usual way of proving that $T$ is bijective consists in proving that it has an inverse, and that inverse is $\operatorname{Id}+T+T^2+T^3+\cdots$, and proving that this makes sense requires completeness.

Comment: I've edited and realised how to make this work, thank you for your example. Would you be able to comment on my corrections?

Comment: It looks correct now.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate proof :

1. Prove that $U = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} T^k$ is well-defined (using the fact that you are in a Banach space !)
2. Prove that $U \circ (I-T)=(I-T) \circ U = I$.

Comment: Is the continuity argument I made alright? And yes, the proof of the above is left as the next exercise which I have done